# Calculating some statistics for each column of a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 4D numpy array of input data where each column represents a quantity (say speed, acceleration, etc) and I would like to calculate some statistical information for each quantity (mean, st-dev. meadian, 75, 85 and 95 percentiles.

So for example:

```
input_shape = (1,200,4)
n_sample = 100

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,) + input_shape)
X.shape
(100, 1, 200, 4)

X[0]
array([[[0.50410922, 0.82829892, 0.72460878, 0.0562701 ],
        [0.49223423, 0.14152948, 0.32285973, 0.49056405],
        ...
        [0.8299407 , 0.78446729, 0.40959698, 0.893117  ],
        [0.25150705, 0.56759064, 0.28280459, 0.0599566 ]]])
```

Each column of `X`  represents some physical quantity for 200 data-points. The statistics of each quantity is what I'm interested in.

**EDIT**

I would expect something like:

```
[[[col1_mean, col2_mean, col3_mean, col4_mean ],
   [col1_std, col2_std, col3_std, col4_mean],
   [col1_med, col2_med, col3_med, col4_med],
   [col1_p75, col2_p75, col3_p75, col4_p75 ],
   [col1_p85, col2_p85, col3_p85, col4_p85 ],
   [col1_p95, col2_p95, col3_p95, col4_p95 ]]]
```

So the result is shaped `(100, 1, 6, 4)`

Comment: your `X` is a 4D array, It's rather unclear what you mean by `std` or 75%-percentile of 3D data.

Comment: @Ah yeah, I should have said 4D instead. Edited.

Comment: What is the "column" along which you want to compute your statistics? Most stats like this can be computed by passing an `axis` argument. For example `np.mean(X, axis=-2)` would return an array of shape `(100, 1, 4)` with the mean across what you call the "200 data points".

Comment: @bnaecker Yes,  the computation is along axis 3 (`axis=-2`) as in your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to compute the statistics of interest by supplying an `axis` argument. This is used by many NumPy functions to run their computation along that axis. For your data, it seems you'd like to compute across the "data points" dimension, which is `axis=2`. For example:

```py
>>> input_shape = (1,200,4)
>>> n_sample = 100
>>> X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,) + input_shape)
>>> X.shape
(100, 1, 200, 4)
>>> X.mean(axis=2).shape  # Compute mean along 3rd axis
(100, 1, 4)
>>> stat_functions = (np.mean, np.std, np.med)
>>> stats = [func(X, axis=2) for func in stat_functions]
>>> list(map(np.shape, stats))
[(100, 1, 4), (100, 1, 4), (100, 1, 4)]
```

You'll have to do a bit more work to create functions to compute the percentiles you're interested in:

```py
>>> import functools
>>> percentiles = tuple(functools.partial(np.percentile, q=q) for q in (75, 85, 95))
>>> stat_functions = (np.mean, np.std, np.median) + percentiles
```

If you want to join these into a single array, you can use the `keepdims` kwarg of each to avoid *removing* the axis along which the function is applied, and then concatenate the results:

```py
>>> stats = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in stat_functions], axis=2)
>>> stats.shape
(100, 1, 6, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a cicle on indexes,
for example if you try this:

```
print(X[0][0][:,0])
```

it prints first column so you can iterate it and append it to a list, then calulate median and sdv.